# Trying to get Image cover adjacent to text in section of bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm trying to have a Bootstrap section that's 1/2 UL & 1/2 image.  The code works fine at full screen, but when I start reducing the size of the screen the image begins to shrink & show the section's background (see images).  hot can I go about having the image always remain full cover in 1/2 of the section until it reaches the break point @ small width?  Thanks for any help you can give!!
[Full Screen works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt9YF.jpg) |  [Image begins to "break" around medium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC2C9.jpg) | [Works fine again at small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Rwp.jpg)

```
<section class="bg-primary-cut" id="cuts">
       <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
                          <h2 class="section-heading-cuts text-uppercase">Pup List</h2>
                          <hr class="light">
                              <ul class="ul-cuts">
                                  <li>Short one </li>
                                  <li>Short one </li>
                                  <li>a little bit longer one </li>
                                  <li>short one </li>
                                  <li>also a tad bit longer </li>
                                  <li>last shortie </li>
                              </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img class="media-object img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/1200/600?image=1062"  height="500">
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Have you tried making the image a background cover image instead?

Comment: ding ding ding!  When I first tried it was not working, but now seems to be A-okay!  thanks for having me go back for a second try

Comment: No problem!  You might run into problems when viewing the site on a mobile device with the cover image property and it'll appear blank... I wrote a short article on how to bullet-proof the cover image design if you'll be viewing the site on mobile devices : http://blog.brainhappy.ca/css-background-size-cover-making-it-work-for-mobile-ios/

Comment: awesome, thank you - I'll be sure to reference it if I run into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the image to 100% so it will fill. Although it may skew it out of proportion.

OR you can see at which point it starts to break and set different styles for that breakpoint with media queries to override bootstraps sm/md/lg breakpoints.